# How to debug scipy.optimize.minimize gradient methods errors/warnings

Tags: python, statistics, scipy

I'm writing a fitting routine for 2d data. In a nutshell, I have 5x5 pixel data that can be modelled with this function of parameters (A, x0, y0, fwhm):

```
from scipy.special import erf

def lambda_g(A, x0, y0, fwhm, bkg, size):
    fwhm *= 0.6
    x, y = np.arange(size), np.arange(size)
    derfx = erf((x + 1 - x0) / fwhm) - erf((x - x0) / fwhm)
    derfy = erf((y + 1 - y0) / fwhm) - erf((y - y0) / fwhm)
    return 0.25 * A * fwhm**2 * np.pi * derfx[:, np.newaxis] * derfy
```

So that simulated data could be:

```
sim = lambda A, x0, y0, fwhm, bkg: lambda_g(A, x0, y0, fwhm, 5) + np.random.normal(bkg, bkg/100, (5, 5))
```

Anyway, I hope you're still with me. I want to fit the data using maximum-likelihood optimization in order to get the parameters A, x0, y0, bkg. So I calculated the loglikelihood function, as well as the jacobian. Here they are:

```
def logll(parameters, *args):
    A, x0, y0, bkg = parameters
    fwhm, area = args

    lambda_p = lambda_g(A, x0, y0, fwhm, area.shape[0]) + bkg
    return -np.sum(area * np.log(lambda_p) - lambda_p)


def ll_jac(parameters, *args):
    A, x0, y0, bkg = parameters
    fwhm, area = args

    size = area.shape[0]
    x, y = np.arange(size), np.arange(size)

    dexpx = np.exp(-((x + 1 - x0)/(fwhm*0.6))**2) - np.exp(-((x - x0)/(fwhm*0.6))**2)
    dexpy = np.exp(-((y + 1 - y0)/(fwhm*0.6))**2) - np.exp(-((y - y0)/(fwhm*0.6))**2)
    derfx = erf((x + 1 - x0) / (fwhm*0.6)) - erf((x - x0) / (fwhm*0.6))
    derfy = erf((y + 1 - y0) / (fwhm*0.6)) - erf((y - y0) / (fwhm*0.6))
    factor = 1 - area/(lambda_g(A, x0, y0, fwhm, size) + bkg)

    jac = np.zeros(4)
    # dL/d(A)
    # The derivative of lambda_g is lambda_g(A=1)
    jac[0] = -np.sum(factor*lambda_g(1, x0, y0, fwhm, size))

    # dL/d(x0) y dL/d(y0)
    # 0.3 = 0.5*0.6
    jac12 = 0.3*A*fwhm*np.sqrt(np.pi)
    jac[1] = jac12*np.sum(dexpx[:, np.newaxis]*derfy*factor)
    jac[2] = jac12*np.sum(dexpy[:, np.newaxis]*derfx*factor)

    # dL/d(bkg)
    jac[3] = -np.sum(factor)

    return jac
```

Fitting routine goes like this:

```
from scipy.ndimage.measurements import center_of_mass
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def fit_area(area, fwhm):

    # First guess of parameters
    bkg = np.min(area)
    A = area[np.floor(area.shape[0]/2), np.floor(area.shape[1]/2)] - bkg
    A /= 0.65
    x0, y0 = center_of_mass(area)

    results = minimize(logll, [A, x0, y0, bkg], args=(fwhm, area),
                       method='CG', options={'disp': True})
    return results.x
```

This works as long as I choose a method like "Powell", that doesn't need a gradient. I'd like to use a gradient method because it's supposed to be faster. 
Using my gradient, I get the warning `Desired error not necessarily achieved due to precision loss.` and really bad results. If I let scipy to estimate the gradient, I also get the warning but good results. And finally, Powell method doesn't give the warning and returns even nicer results.

I'm about to quit gradient methods and stick to Powell. Is there anything I can try before that?

Comment: in derfy in lambda_g you probably want to subtract y0 instead of x0 from y

Comment: yes, I made the mistake while copying the code here

Comment: check your gradient numerically

Comment: you mean with scipy.optimize.check_grad ? I did, it returns ~10000 when all four parameters are considered and ~10 when only [A, bkg] are used. What should I conclude from these tests?